# Outlook modifies link for local images itself, how to prevent that?

Tags: html, file, url, outlook, newsletter

I currently would like to send newsletters to all the people of a specific company.

For privacy and security reasons I'm forced to host all the newsletters on their own server, including the images, I can't put that content on a web server.

Because of that, all the URLS and images are network urls e.g

'file://nameOfTheServer.something.cool/newsletters/img.jpg'

However, I'm not on the same network, I send the newsletters from my office.
Because of that, I have the feeling that at the insertion of the emails, Outlook 2010 doesn't find the local urls and modifies it.

'file://nameoftheserver' becomes  'file:///\nameoftheserver', therefore, the image isn't displayed anymore once received by the people.

If I try to send the same e-mail with another e-mail adress, while being on the same network, this works, the urls aren't modified, and are still the same...

Any idea on a way I could solve it ?

Regards,

Comment: You could try to put “\\” at the beginning of address. Like this:

<a href = \\“ & Path &”>

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the format of URL address, it is very important to properly reference resources to be loaded from a web server, even if it is an intranet. As you mention you're using file:// but for this case you really must use http://, be aware that external links to resources (any that is not attached on same email message) can be blocked (in this case images) by email clients, antivirus software or even the email provider. Because of this, probably, people who read the email will get a warning about external content being loaded, and images won't show properly until the reader confirm to load the images from the external site (even intranet is considered an external one).

Maybe, you're wondering about some emails you received that shows images when opened and no warning is shown, It is because images are not being referenced from external sites, images are included inside email's body as attachment so it is a local reference which is considered "safe".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I edit the link and use HTTP, that still doesn't work... I can see that the entire image tag is stripped from the e-mail... sadly.